# Is there a continuous $f(x,y)$ which is not of the form $f(x,y) = g_1(x) h_1(y) + \dots + g_n(x) h_n(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For a continuous function $f : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, let us say $f$ is a *sum of products (SOP)* if there exist an integer $n > 0$ and continuous functions $g_1, \dots, g_n, h_1, \dots, h_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x,y) = g_1(x) h_1(y) + \dots + g_n(x) h_n(y)$$
for all $x,y \in [0,1]$.

How can I show there exists a continuous $f$ which is *not* an SOP?

I think this should be easy, but for some reason I don't see how to proceed.

Note that the Stone-Weierstrass theorem says that every continuous function on $[0,1]^2$ is a uniform limit of SOPs.  I want to see that you can't drop the limit.

Is the same true if we replace $[0,1]$ by an arbitrary infinite compact Hausdorff space?

Comment: Why not sin(xy)

Comment: I was going to suggest $e^{xy}$, @Nitin.

Comment: Fine, but how do I prove they are not SOPs?

Comment: Taylor series has infinitely many terms. For a fixed x and y you can make it finite using error estimates though

Comment: @Nitin: I don't see how that helps.  The Taylor series for $f(x,y) = e^x$ also has infinitely many terms, but it is an SOP.

Comment: @Nitin However, that does not prove that there is no other representation, with only finitely many products. While it is "obvious" that they are not SOPs, proving it isn't obvious.

Comment: The confusion might be that some people require $g_i$ and $h_i$ to be *polynomials* while the OP suggested just continuous functions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's call $f$ an $n$-SOP if we can write

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{k = 1}^n g_k(x)\cdot h_k(y)$$

with continuous functions $g_k, h_k \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is an $n$-SOP, for every family $x_1 < x_2 < \dotsc < x_r$ of $r > n$ points in $[0,1]$, the set

$$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} f(x_1,y) \\ f(x_2,y) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_r,y)\end{pmatrix} : y \in [0,1]\right\}$$

is contained in an $n$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^r$.

But

$$\begin{pmatrix} \exp (x_1\cdot 0/r) & \exp (x_1\cdot 1/r) & \cdots & \exp (x_1 \cdot (r-1)/r) \\ \exp (x_2 \cdot 0/r) & \exp (x_2 \cdot 1/r) & \cdots & \exp (x_2 \cdot (r-1)/r) \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ \exp (x_r\cdot 0/r) & \exp (x_r\cdot 1/r) & \cdots & \exp (x_r \cdot (r-1)/r)\end{pmatrix}$$

is a Vandermonde matrix, hence has rank $r$. Therefore $(x,y) \mapsto e^{xy}$ is not an $n$-SOP.

Comment: That's a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

We have a writing $f(x,y) =\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x) h_i(y)$, equivalently
$$f(\cdot, y) = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i(y) g_i(\cdot)$$
means that the system of function   $(f(\cdot, y))_y$ is  contained in the span of n functions $g_i(\cdot)$, $i=1, \ldots, n$, equivalently,
this system of functions $(f(\cdot, y))_y$ has rank at most $n$ ( remember: functions are "vectors" ).

But for a general function $f(x,y)$ ( analytic, not a polynomial) the system $(f(\cdot, y))_y$ is infinite dimensional ($e^{x y}$ (@Daniel Fischer: answer), $\frac{1}{x+y}$, $\sqrt{x+y}$, $\frac{1}{1-x y}$ $\&$ c.)

It's worth looking at $f(x,y)$ as an infinite matrix indexed by $x$, $y$. There exists such a writing if and only if the matrix has rank $\le n$, that is, if and only if every minor
$$\det (f(x_i, y_j))_{i,j=1, n+1}=0$$