# Density of a set in the space of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, continuity

Let $C([0, 1])$ be the set of continuous real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$, 
and the same with $V:=C([0, 1]\times[0, 1])$ (the is a normed space with the maximum metric). Let $W\subset V$ be the subspace of all functions that can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)g_i(y)$ where $f_i, g_i \in C([0, 1])$. Show that $W$ is dense in $V$.

Well, since $W$ is a subspace, then the closure is also a subspace. Every $f\in V$
has a bound $M$ and then $f=(f+M)+(-1)M$ so it's sufficient to show that every non-negative $f$ is in the closure. But that's the best reduction I could find and I don't know how to continue. Any ideas?

Comment: For the users who would be interested, $W \neq V$, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355311).

Comment: Do you know the stone weierstrass theorem?

Comment: In the one-dimentional version (on a closed interval), yes

Comment: The Stone–Weierstrass theorem can be found in Anton Deitmar and Siegried Echterhoff, _Principles of Harmonic Analysis_, 1st edition, theorem A.10.1. It is far more general that the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: If you know the convolution, then take $h_\epsilon(x,y) = \frac{1}{\epsilon 2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/\epsilon^2}$ an analytic and entire approximation  of the Dirac delta, so that if $f$ is (uniformly) continuous on $[0,1]^2$ then $f \ast h_\epsilon$ is an entire approximation of $f$ for the supremum norm on $[0,1]^2$. Finally, the polynomials are dense for the supremum norm on $[0,1]^2$ in the entire functions

Comment: @35T41 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Stone.E2.80.93Weierstrass_theorem.2C_real_version